# Go shared libraries for Docker containers to share

Tags: go, docker

In Docker is there a way to put Go shared libraries that are needed by containerized go apps in a read only shared memory area? The objective is to allow many containers to the execute the same code reducing memory requirements in the containers. I expect a side effect would be smaller container images.

Where would these Go shared libraries be in memory?

Comment: Why not just compile statically linked binaries for the apps that you need, and put them in your containers? Go binaries are usually not that big that you need to be worried about excessive disk usage. One of the great things about Go is it allows you to build self-contained, statically linked binaries, and one of the great things about Docker is it allows you to build self-contained, isolated... well... containers. You'd have to have a pretty compelling reason to circumvent these two nice features in the interest of saving a bit of disk space.

Comment: I'm not trying to save disk space.  I trying to reduce memory consumption by loading my Go shared libraries into a memory region that will be shared by all containers.  I want the isolation that Docker provides but with less memory use.  Think thousands of containers.

Answer (score 0):

The image size is less about memory and more about disk space.

You could set those shared dynamic library in an image of their own, with a shared VOLUME path.

You then docker create a container based on that image: that is a [data volume container](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container).

Finally, you reuse that created container as many time as you want, with a [`--volumes-from=<yourCreatedContainer>`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems) for each go app `docker run` containers.